# Query for the history of the customer standard payment term in oracle r12

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle10g, oracle-ebs

I would like to ask for your help if there is an oracle table that saves the history of customer standard payment terms in r12. This is like the table `ar_credit_histories` which saves changes in credit rating and credit limit but instead contains the previous standard payment terms. I have tried searching for it but all I can find are the transactional payment terms used.

Hoping for your response and thank you for your time.

Edit 1: Here is my current code, this is wrong since it is returning the Payment terms used per transaction, not the standard payment term history.

```sql
Select * 
from (
  select t.*, 
    lag(t."Payment Term") 
      over (partition by t."Account Number" order by t."Creation Date") as lag_pay
  from (
    select 
      hca.account_name "Account Name",
      hca.account_number "Account Number",
      rt.name "Payment Term",
      rt.description "Description",
      trunc (apsa.creation_date) "Creation Date",
      trunc (apsa.last_update_date) "Last Update Date"
    from ra_terms rt, hz_cust_accounts hca, ar_payment_schedules_all apsa
    where apsa.class = 'INV'
    and apsa.invoice_currency_code = 'USD'
    and apsa.customer_id = hca.cust_account_id (+)
    and apsa.term_id = rt.term_id
    group by 
      apsa.creation_date,
      rt.name,
      rt.description,
      hca.account_name,
      hca.account_number,
      apsa.last_update_date,
      apsa.trx_number
    order by hca.account_number DESC, "Creation Date" ASC
  ) t
)
Where lag_pay is null 
or lag_pay <> "Payment Term"
```

Comment: Table structure, sample data and expected output please

Comment: @Tejash, I have edited my post. Thanks!

Comment: Still you need to edit the question as it is very much unclear. What is actual and expected output? Also put some sample data.